# How to check if a div has element innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div, which contains n number of child nodes.
I have a for loop:

```
for (iloop = 0; iloop < summaryDiv.childNodes.length; iloop++) {
    if (summaryDiv.childNodes[iloop].innerHTML.contains('display:block')) {
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

Here some of the child nodes don't contain the element innerHTML. I need to check if the child node contains innerHTML element, then I need to check for the style (display:block).
How can I do this?

Comment: Changed all occurrences of `innerHtml` in question to `innerHTML`—JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check the style of something, you do not need `innerHTML`.  Instead, access the `display` value directly from the `style` element that is defined by default on DOM elements.

```
var children = summaryDiv.childNodes; // Avoid excessive scope chain walking (faster!)
for ( var i=0, l=children.length; i<l; i++ ) {
    if ( children[i].style && children[i].style.display == "block" ) {
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: if ( children[i].style && children[i].style.display == "block" ) {

Getting error here.
says children[iloop].style is undefined

Comment: @Nimesh: Check what the value of `children[i]` is (`alert(children[i]);`). It probably isn't a DOM element if the `style` property is undefined.

Comment: @Nimesh Change `iloop` to `i`. I've made an edit, make sure you have the updated version.  @Steve The DOM text node element doesn't define a `style` property, which is why the `children[i].style` check is in place (Nimesh is probably using an older version of the code, I did make an edit).

Comment: This only looks at immediate children whereas the OP's question with innerHTML looked at all nested chilren.

Answer (score 1):

Use the display property directly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < summaryDiv.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (summaryDiv.childNodes[i].style && summaryDiv.childNodes[i].style.display == 'block') {
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error here
summaryDiv.childNodes[i][iloop].style is undefined

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing [i][iloop]. Do you really have nested loops? The [i] should be all you need. The check for .style will prevent the style property from ever being used if it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element has a property "innerHTML".

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="div">hello</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.write("div: " + ("innerHTML" in document.getElementById("div")));
    document.write("<br />");
    document.write("div.child: " + ("innerHTML" in document.getElementById("div").firstChild));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

produces:

```
div: true
div.child: false
```